# Linux has or does not have an extension

Tags: linux, operating-system

It is said that Linux OS does not have any extension in files.

But there are .rpm, .sh files.

Who can explain it?

Are .rpm and .sh not extensions?

Thanks!

Comment: this question is normal, but no one is able to answer and why do you dislike my topic instead of advising?

Comment: Who said Linux does not have any file extension?

Comment: Books, video tutorials

Answer (score 2):

### Linux  doesn't  Need File Extensions

linux doesn't care about extensions, it doesn't open files based on there extensions.
I think files have header and they are opened based on there header informations.
but you can make a file which has an extension, as it will be easier for you to understand the type of file in future

```
$ touch myscript.sh

$ touch myscript
```

you can run both scripts:

```
$ ./myscript.sh

$ ./myscript
```

### Is Extensions Used In Linux?

YES, Sometimes.
as I said, linux doesn't care about extensions *BUT*, **There are some programs in linux like gunzip, that need a file that has .gz extension.**
I mean that the programmer of gunzip has written his program in a way that it looks at the extension of file.
so if you have zip file that doesn't have .gz extension, first you need to change its name and put .gz at the end of it's name.

```
$ gunzip your_zip
  gzip: your_zip: unknown suffix -- ignored

$ mv your_zip   your_zip.gz

$ gunzip    your_zip.gz
```

Now it's ok

### Check File Type

type command is for checking the type of files

```
$ type your_zip.gz
  your_zip.gz: gzip compressed data

$ type your_zip
  your_zip: gzip compressed data
```

if "your_zip" is a zip file, the result of both commands will be zip

Answer (score 1):

Some file systems break the file specifier into a filename and an extension.

```
FILENAME . EXTENSION
```

The period is not part of the internally stored file name. It act like the /\ [] directory separators and breaks the file specifier into separate components. These components are stored separately in the file tables and directories.

The various Windoze/MS-DOG, mainframe, and VMS file systems are examples.

Linux does not. It just has FILENAME. If you have "xyz.sh" the period is just another character in the file name.

Some applications on Linux expect file names to follow certain conventions. The form of the name (xyz.c, xyz.o) indicate to the application how to process the file.

There is no extension component of the filename on most  Unix file systems. What you are thinking of as a file extension is just a file naming convention.